# Java Bean Projection

Tags: java, javabeans, projection

Are there any libraries that easily allow projections of Java beans?

I have a bean written with getters and setters as per the Javabean convention, and at runtime in different places I want to take a fully-populated bean, and create a new instance with only  a subset of its properties populated from the original.

Could something like QueryDSL be used for this? Jackson has views that could be used in the context of JSON serialization, but I was looking for a Java-to-Java solution.

Comment: Querydsl uses Apache BeanUtils internally, so it makes to try out BeanUtils.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Dozer](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/) is a bean-mapper that will copy properties using reflection. It can be configured to include only a subset of properties if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Apache Commons BeanUtils](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/)

Comment: -1 If you don't have the time or inclination to give a full answer, then don't write it at all. Even for a comment this is sketchy.